# Find the general solution to the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{2xy+y^2+1}{x^2+2xy}$$

How do I find the general solution? I can not tell which method to use to even solve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$(2xy+y^2+1)dx+(x^2+2xy)dy=0$$
and with $M=2xy+y^2+1$, $N=x^2+2xy$ we see
$\displaystyle\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} = 2x+2y=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$ that is **exact** equation.

Answer (score 0):

Call $s=x^2+2yx$, obtaining $$y=\frac{s}{2x}-\frac x2\\ \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac1{2x}\frac{ds}{dx}-\frac{s}{2x^2}-\frac12$$ hence $$\frac1{2x}\frac{ds}{dx}-\frac{s}{2x^2}-\frac12=-\frac{s-x^2+\left(\frac s{2x}-\frac x2\right)^2+1}{s}=-\frac{s-x^2+\frac{s^2}{4x^2}-\frac s2+\frac{x^2}4+1}{s}\\s\frac{ds}{dx}-\frac{s^2}{x}-sx=-2sx+2x^3-\frac{s^2}{2x}+sx-\frac{x^3}{2}-2x\\s\frac{ds}{dx}-\frac{s^2}{2x}=\frac32x^3-2x\\\frac 1xs\frac{ds}{dx}-\frac{s^2}{2x^2}=\frac32x^2-2\\\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{s^2}{2x}\right)=\frac32x^2-2$$

> *Disclaimer:* Since I might have made some mistake of calculation (ultimately invalidating my work), I encourage you to check directly whether the function $L=x(x+2y)^2$ satisfies the equation $$\frac{dL}{dx}=3x^2-4$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the same initial change of variable as G. Sassatelli in his/her answer, considering the equation
$$y' = -\frac{2xy+y^2+1}{x^2+2xy}$$

$$x^2+2xy=s\implies y=\frac{s-x^2}{2 x}\implies y'=-\frac{s-x s'+x^2}{2 x^2}$$ makes the equation $$2 x s s'-s^2=3 x^4-4 x^2$$ Now, using $t=s^2$ $$x t'-t=3x^4-4x^2$$ $$xt-t=0\implies t=C x$$ Variation of parameters $$C'=3x^2-4\implies C=x^3-4x+K\implies t=x^4-4x^2+Kx$$ $$ s=\pm \sqrt{x^4-4x^2+Kx}$$ $$y=\frac{\pm \sqrt{x^4-4x^2+Kx}-x^2}{2x}$$